# i want to put some text infront of some line on the border style?, is this a z-index style?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't post images because it says that I need 10 reputation to post images so here's the link. 
[click here](https://plus.google.com/117699456669419109682/posts/Tq9EpdVE4fZ?pid=6157104314030525714&oid=117699456669419109682)

Because I want to put some text in-front of some of the border line,
Need your suggestion/tips guys.

Comment: Do you have any of it written yet? Can we see what you've tried?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and tell us what you have observed.

Comment: its ok now, i've found out now and its a fieldset tag :)
 thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are showing in your image is a fieldset.

```html
<fieldset>
     <legend>I'm a Fieldset</legend>
     Stuff<br>
     Stuff
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a text blocks splitted with vertical lines like that?

```css
.lined {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.lined > div {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1em;
}

.lined > div + div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: -1px;
  width: 0;
  height: 80%;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="lined">
  <div>The display property specifies the type of rendering box used for an element. In HTML, default display property values are taken from behaviors described in the HTML specifications or from the browser/user default stylesheet. The default value in XML is inline.</div>
  <div>In addition to the many different display box types, the value none lets you turn off the display of an element; when you use none, all descendant elements also have their display turned off. The document is rendered as though the element doesn't exist in the document tree.</div>
  <div>CSS is one of the core languages of the open web and has a standardized W3C specification. Developed in levels, CSS1 is now obsolete, CSS2.1 is a recommendation, and CSS3, now split into smaller modules, is progressing on the standardization track.</div>
</div>
```